# Insert a quote in a string

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm looking to insert a quote in a string, but keep everything else. So, an example string:
`' "2020-10-10",8000,"Hello" '`

I want to put quotes around 8000 (or whatever number is there). so:
`' "2020-10-10","8000","Hello" '`

How would I do that in regex?

Comment: is it always the second element that need quotes ? Or sometimes it's the date, some it's the third element...

Comment: It's not always the second element, and there are multiple occurrences. I was trying to simplify the question, but the string contains 50+ variables mixed with dates, numbers and text.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts incluiding links to the most relevant quesitons and answer as well the most relevant parts of them, as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Why is your expected result not: `' ""2020"-"10"-"10"", "8000", "Hello" '` ? Is your input actually a form of CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on regex but you can do it you just have to do it twice.  Because I couldn't figure out a way to look for ",char or char,".

```
function test() {
  try {
    let a = ' "2020-10-10",8000,"Hello" ';
    a = a.replace(/,/g,'","');
    a = a.replace(/""/g,'"');
    console.log(a);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

7:26:23 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:26:23 AM  Info     "2020-10-10","8000","Hello" 
7:26:23 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```